# Convergence of $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin x} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

> Is the following integral improper? If so, does it converge?
>   $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin x} dx$$

I approached the problem as follows:

Since $\sin(0) = 0$ the integral is improper at $0$.

The integral will converge if both

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{0} \frac{1}{\sin x} dx$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin x} dx$$

converge.

Let $a \in (0, \pi/2)$. Substitute  $\tan\frac{x}{2} = 2$, so $x(t) = 2\arctan(t)$.

Now we get

$$\int_{a}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin x} dx = \int_{a}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\frac{2t}{1+t^2}} \frac{2}{1+t^2} dt = \int_{a}^{\pi/2} \frac{2}{2t} dt = \biggr\rvert_{c}^{\pi/2} \ln(t) = \ln(\pi/2) - \ln(c)$$

and since $\ln(c) \to -\infty,$ when $c \to 0^+$ we can conclude that the integral will diverge.

My question is that can I approach this a different way so that I wouldn't have to use Weierstrass substitution? Also, I'm a bit confused about the interchange of limits when using the Weierstrass substitution, as seen I did not apply this here and I'm not sure if it's applicable to do so.

Comment: "Since $\sin(0)=0$ the integral is improper at $0$." You're misusing the term [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) there, but I think you're trying to imply $\sin(0)=0$ is enough to prove $\int_0^\epsilon\frac{1}{\sin x}dx$ diverges for any $\epsilon>0$. It's actually not; consider e.g. $\int_0^\epsilon\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$.

Comment: Hmm, could you elaborate a bit? At $x = 0$ we would be in a situation where we would have to divide by $0$, hence we should treat the integral as improper?

Comment: An "improper integral" is really a limit of a sequence or function that returns integrals, rather than a single integral. The point of my example is that an integral can converge even if its integrand doesn't converge at each endpoint. *How fast* the integrand diverges is also important.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$ and $x < \pi/2$ we  have  $\sin x \le x. $

Next steps : reciprocals and comparison test.